# Should a BOM (byte order mark) be added for empty strings (UTF-16 and UTF-32)?

Tags: utf-16, string, byte-order-mark, convention, utf-32

Excluding UTF-8, is there a general understanding, or unspoken of convention, that if a string is empty the encoder can (should) safely omit the BOM.

It seems like it would be a waste for empty strings, especially when sending to a server.
Encoding type and byte order would be irrelevant in such a case.

Is there an RFC that specifically addresses BOM for empty strings?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A BOM is typically used only when there is no other external information about the string's encoding.  Makes sense for text files, the data has to be self-describing, but not so much for transmission protocols unless there is no other encoding information available, like the `Content-Type` header in HTTP, the `<meta>` tag for HTML, hard-coded by protocol specs or protocol extensions, etc.

For simply storing a string in memory, a BOM is useless if you are tracking the string properly.  Also, depending on the particular string type you are actually using, an empty string may or may not be implemented as a NULL pointer, so you might not be able to include a BOM anyway.

And no, there is no RFC about general BOM usage.

Comment: In my case the encoded string as a portion of some generic binary data being sent to a server for processing/storage. How the server stores it doesn't matter, but upon arrival the server may be strictly checking/requiring/enforcing BOMs as it unpacks the data. However for an empty string this doesn't make sense. Should the server care?

Comment: @Dabbu, it sounds like a custom protocol then. You are going to have to ask the folks in charge of the server to see what they expect. It's up to them.

Comment: @Dabbu: protocols should dictate the encoding of any strings used. If the protocol you are using to talk to the server does not dictate a specific encoding, you will have to talk to the protocol vendor/author to find out.

Comment: In this scenario, I'm in control of both client and server.
I guess the question is more on BOM theory, regarding best coding practices.

Comment: If you are in control off both ends, then dictate the encoding in your protocol. I would suggest UTF-8 instead of UTF-16.